# Compound terms and Lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Why are compound terms preferable over lists in terms of performance?
For example,

```
matrix(row(1,2,3),row(1,2,3),row(1,2,3))
```

is preferable over

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something that the other (excellent) answer did not mention:

Access to the member of a list by its position means that you need to traverse the list. Access to the argument of a term should be possible in constant time. So for random access a term should be more efficient.

---

Short aside: you can attempt to make the list traversal marginally faster. But the [SWI-Prolog implementation of `nth0_det/3`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#nth0/3) almost smells of desperation ;)

---

You might be interested in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swi-prolog/-9UZtOhtZHg), esp. [this summary](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/swi-prolog/-9UZtOhtZHg/vXG6KRxEGAAJ) that talks about lists and terms among other things.

A few rules of thumb follow.

Use case:

- if you know in advance how many things you have, use a term.
- if you can have 0 or more of the same things, use a list.
- if you need a look-up table, neither is optimal

Efficiency:

- if you want random access, use a term
- if your algorithm works well on a singly-linked list, a Prolog list is perfectly good choice.

From the last point follows: try to find algorithms that use linked lists, not random-access arrays. It is not always possible, but for many problems you have a choice. The classical example would be a quick sort vs. a merge sort: in Prolog, a merge sort is definitely quicker.

Either way, first make sure you get it right, then worry about efficiency. And make sure you measure the performance bottlenecks before starting to optimize.

Choosing an optimal algorithm and data structure means, of course, that you need to know both your problem and the available tools. Not relevant to your problem, but the beauty of what used to be the "Standard Template Library" for C++ is that for both algorithms and data structures, time complexity ("big O notation") is an inherent property, not an implementation detail.

Comment: Are you sure about "The classical example would be a quick sort vs. a merge sort: in Prolog, a merge sort is definitely quicker."?

Comment: @repeat For sorting lists in pure prolog, i personally could not come up with a quicksort implementation that came close to my own mergesort implementation. So this sentence says more about me than about anything else.

Comment: Haha, only serious:) But honestly... have you exhaustively searched for these cases yet? I have not (yet). Be that as it may... In the meantime take some comfort in one of Linus' quotes: "*Theory and practice sometimes clash. And when that happens, theory loses. Every single time.*"

Comment: @repeat You actually gave me an idea: in SWI-Prolog at least, `=..` is quite fast. I wonder if turning a list into a term and using `nb_setarg` for the swap would make the quicksort quicker (this would also avoid quite a bit of garbage creation/collection maybe?). I don't know if this would be "cheating".

Comment: How about moving this from the SO-comment level to the SO-question level?

Comment: @repeat If I had enough time (which I don't at the moment), I need to ask two somewhat connected question: this, and also about "mapping terms" (`mapterm` in analogy to `maplist`). But good questions are difficult and time consuming :(

Comment: Looking forward to it! Take your time.

Comment: @repeat The thing with Prolog and sorting is that there is very little practical reason not to use the built-in sorts. Esp. since SWI-Prolog has the `sort/4` predicate I can't find a good excuse for playing around with sorting in pure Prolog.

Comment: `sort/2` and `keysort/2` sure are very useful. But preserving logical purity is important, too! Consider comparatively new SICStus predicates `clpfd:sorting/3` and `clpfd:keysorting/[2,3]` (URL https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Arithmetic_002dLogical-Constraints.html)

Answer (score 7):

First, just to be clear: Lists *are* a kind of compound term.

To see what lists are, use `write_canonical/1`. For example, using GNU Prolog:

```
| ?- write_canonical([1,2,3]).  
'.'(1,'.'(2,'.'(3,[])))
```

Regarding representation in memory, I recommend Richard O'Keefe's book. The details differ between systems, but you can be pretty sure that to represent the term `row(1,2,3)` in memory, you need:

- one memory cell for the functor/arity
- 3 memory cells for the arguments

For the term `.(1, .(2, .(3, [])` in a straight-forward memory representation, you need:

- 3 memory cells for the three `'.'/2` functors
- 3 memory cells for 1, 2, 3
- likely some more (such as for `[]`).

From this, you already see that using lists takes at least roughly **twice** as much memory in this representation.

A few simple tests that you can carry out yourself will help you to see the difference in memory consumption of these representations for your system.

Comment: This is very interesting. In terms of computation, you know how this representations compare?

Comment: Two other important aspects are *(first) argument indexing* (see your Prolog system or a good book) and *arity limits*: With lists, the only entitites are the atom `[]` and terms `'.'/2`, so (shallow) first argument indexing *cannot* distinguish (for examples) lists of length 1, 2, 3 etc. In favour of lists: Your Prolog system may have inheret limits on the *arity* of compound terms, so in some cases, using a list-like structure may be required to represent a collection of very many elements. Richard's book contains more valuable information about both aspects and more.

Answer (score 4):

Another aspect is time performance when accessing a specific element. With a list, you get linear access to its elements. But with a compound term of the form `functor(arg1, arg2, ..., argn, ...)`, we can use the standard `arg/3` built-in predicate for constant access to any argument. I.e. O(N) versus O(1) with any sensible Prolog implementation.

But there's no definitive answer to your question as formulated. The best solution depends on the particular problem you're solving. For example, applying an operation to all arguments may be faster with a list (compared with using a solution based on `arg/3`). But it will also depend on the used Prolog system. If performance is a main concern, benchmarking is key. Just avoid doing it at a micro-level and instead take into account how the term is created and accessed in all parts of your application that deal with it.